# Particle Shader Raycast

Tags: three.js, shader, raycasting, particles

I'm trying to recreate an effect similar to this http://opencontinents.com/details/big-man/?stars=1
I would like to have particles of a geometry to react to mouse position.

I'm currently using raycasting and altering the vertices of my geometry on mouseDown ( pushing away all the vertices hit by the raycast) but the result is quite clunky.

I'm thinking I should approach this with a shader solution rather that altering the vertex but I have no idea where to start.

Would anyone have any suggestions for a good tutorial?

Comment: Questions asking us to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: For example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_gpgpu_birds.html

Comment: I've found this tutorial which is a very good starting point to learn how to deal with shaders.. https://thebookofshaders.com/